# Character coding on Tumblr: how it affects SEO?

Tags: seo, html, tumblr, character-set

So I have a blog on Tumblr I use with my own domain name. I started it to try out how can I SEO it on my own money so I can learn new stuff. So far so good.

As I started to use HTML edit mode on Tumblr I noticed that it does not use UTF8 to my best understanding.

In Rich Text mode I write:

```
"méltán"
```

after editing and saving in HTML edit mode it becomes:

```
"m&eacute;lt&aacute;n"
```

How does such encoding in the source affect SEO? Google and others will see them az é,á,ö,ű etc. or I wouldn't use Tumblr for Hungarian text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I would have written this as a comment but I still don't have the ability to)

After trying it out on various edit modes, the output is always the same `m&eacute;lt&aacute;n` in the source code though it renders as proper letters in the browser.

Search engines treat é, ė, ę as e, same for á, ą as a and etc. So probably they're smart enough to change these codes to the most basic Latin letters.

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr does use UTF-8.   Here is a Chinese blog on Tumblr.   They need UTF-8 to display the Chinese characters.   I've use page info to verify that the character set of the blog's home page is indeed UTF-8.

[image]